# Typoscript: Can't get field imagecaption

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I don't know why I can't get the field imagecaption, every other field works.
I want to display the imagecaption in my lightbox. The field is not empty, so that's not the problem.

In the database, the content looks like this:

```
Praxis
Tulpen
Pinguine
Leuchtturm
```

Any ideas?

My Code:

```
       1 {
          10 = IMAGE
          10.file.import.current = 1
          10.file.import = uploads/pics/
          10.file.maxW = 270


          10.imageLinkWrap = 1
          10.imageLinkWrap {



            enable = 1
            typolink.parameter = TEXT
            typolink.parameter.field = image

            typolink.parameter.split {

              token = ,
              cObjNum = 1
              max = 1

              1.current = 1
              1.wrap = /uploads/pics/|


            }

            typolink.ATagParams = TEXT
            typolink.ATagParams.field = uid
            typolink.ATagParams.wrap = rel="lightbox[lb|]"

            typolink.title.field = imagecaption


          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to TSRef, typolink.title is of type string/stdwrap. It is not a TEXT object.

So what should work is this:

```
typolink.title.cObject = TEXT
typolink.title.cObject.field = imagecaption
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me. If I use uid as field, it works perfect. !?!?!

Comment: that's weird. what are the exact contents of that database field

Comment: Praxis Tulpen Pinguine Leuchtturm is the content, separated with line breaks. I also tried to split, but with the same empty result

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I can help you there. Do you have the same problem if there is only one line and no linebreak in the db field?